# Moving from MySQL to MySQLi message not displaying on no results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i'm currently trying to start using MySQLi instead of MySQL, but for some reason that I don't understand this is working for the first part of changing the password, but then failing on the error message. Can anyone tell me why? Cheers

```
$sql1 = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM Users
    WHERE UserID = '$UserID'
    && Password = '$hashedPW'
SQL;

if ($db->query($sql1)) {
        $sql2 = $db->query("UPDATE Users SET Password = '$NEWhashedPW' WHERE UserID=$UserID");
            if($db->affected_rows === 0) { echo $_SESSION['changepass'] = 'error'; header('Location:'.$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]); 
            } else {
            $_SESSION['changepass'] = 'success'; header('Location:'.$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
            }
} else {
            echo 'error';
}

$result1->free();
$db->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Question, why are you looping through the data if only 1 result is being returned?

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE `UserID` = ".$UserID." AND `Password` = '".$hashedPW."'";
$result = $db->query($sql1);
if($db->num_rows($result)) { // Assuming you have a num_rows() function
    $db->query("UPDATE `Users` SET `Password` = '".$NEWhashedPW."' WHERE `UserID` = ".$UserID);
    $_SESSION['changepass'] = !$db->affected_rows() ? 'error' : 'success';
    header('Location:'.$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
} else
    echo "User not found";
$result1->free();
$db->close();
```

This is also assuming that your query() function has some form of debugging ability and that you have a num_rows() function
If not, write one!

The num_rows() function should work similar to this (procedural style):

```
function num_rows($res) {
    return mysqli_num_rows($res);
}
```

Simply whack that into your database class and you *should* be good to go.
*May need edits, I don't know how your DB class is set up*

Comment: How does your select query (as I used to use) and this:

`$sql1 = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM Users
 WHERE UserID = '$UserID'
 && Password = '$hashedPW'
SQL;`

Differ? I've found so many conflicting suggestions on MySQLi calls it's all a bit confusing!

Comment: "Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::num_rows()" Guess that means I don't have a num_rows() function?

Comment: For me, it's personal preference. That, and I tend to stay away from heredoc formats. They're not as flexible as a standard statement.

Comment: Also, fatal error, that means you don't have a num_rows() function. Write one haha. The basic jist of it should be this (moved to main answer)